# Question locking and migration?

Tags: discussion

Grrr, I had a nice garden related answer ready to go on the ginger question, but it was migrated to a different forum 3 seconds before I hit post. Evidently the system when it saves drafts does not take this into account when allowing migration? Too late now of course, but 15 minutes gone up in smoke.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Colin but it was definitely a cooking question.  The original poster even wondered where it should go.

If it is any consolation I didn't have the question open for migration for more than the time it takes to type Seasoned Advice so I guess it's just bad timing.
Sorry!

Comment: No problem Kevin. I considered it to be a garden question from the point of view of moisture content in beans, potatoes, luffa, all similar situations with meaningful lessons to be learned for gardeners. I'm surprised there is no warning pops up for mods when a draft exists, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to find yourself with an answer that’s suddenly missing a question, you could write a corresponding question yourself  (hello, Jeopardy!) and make sure that it’s on topic for the site. You must have seen something in the original post that prompted you to write an answer.

Admittedly, I am not sure how long the answer will be cached once the question is gone, so the system may thwart that suggestion.